# Как быстро открывать найденные файлы в Nano?

Tags: grep, bash, ubuntu

Я сейчас часто работаю в консоли. Поиск по файлам командой grep:

```
$ grep -nr "шаблон" .
```

Результирующая выдача:

```
./path0/name0:0: Найденная строка
...
./path9/name9:9: Найденная строка
```

После этого я выбираю нужную строчку и открываю в nano:

```
$ nano +5 ./path5/name5
```

Цифру +5 я ввожу вручную. Проделывается эта операция сотни раз за день. Есть ли способ, который позволит как-то избежать этого?

Answer (score 2):

Уверен что есть более адекватные решения, но в голову пришло только это.
 nano таким образом не запустился, зато запустились vi и gedit, другого ничего не пробовал =)

```
grep -nr "шаблон" | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2}' | awk '{ print "+"$2" "$1}' | xargs редактор
```

Answer (score 2):

nano по какой-то причине тупит и не хочет работать нормально в циклах, поэтому можно применять такой подход

```
nano `grep -nrIo  "test" . | awk -F: '{print "+"$2 " " $1}' `
```

К сожалению, при таком подходе nano открывает по многу раз один и тот же файл, если в одном файле найдено несколько результатов.

Comment: А можно в двух словах о том, что делают обратные кавычки? Я их как-то использовал для сборки objective-c кода в линухе, но их значения не узнал...

Comment: Они нужны для того, чтобы выполнять подстановку. Сначала выполняется греп|авк, а потом текст, который был возвращён подстанавливается как аргумент для nano.

Comment: Спасибо, перед написанием своего ответа как раз пытался найти что-то подобное.

Answer (score 2):

nano `grep -m 1 -n "test" . | awk -F: '{print "+"$2 " " $1}'`

Comment: Да-да, -m - то что надо. Объединив наши ответы можно добиться результата.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# 1. Search for text in files using Ripgrep
# 2. Interactively restart Ripgrep with reload action
# 3. Open the file in nano
RG_PREFIX="rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case "
INITIAL_QUERY="${*:-}"
IFS=: read -ra selected < <(
  FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX $(printf %q "$INITIAL_QUERY")" \
  fzf --ansi \
      --disabled --query "$INITIAL_QUERY" \
      --bind "change:reload:sleep 0.1; $RG_PREFIX {q} || true" \
      --delimiter : \
      --preview 'bat --color=always {1} --highlight-line {2}' \
      --preview-window 'up,60%,border-bottom,+{2}+3/3,~3'
)
[ -n "${selected[0]}" ] && nano -l "+${selected[1]}" "${selected[0]}"
```

чуть переделанный под `nano` скрипт - [Using fzf as interative Ripgrep launcher](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#using-fzf-as-interactive-ripgrep-launcher)

в скрипте задействованы утилиты: [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat)